# Cannot retrieve my account in stackoverflow

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have an account with username 'zeb'. My browser was giving me trouble so I upgraded it and now I can't find my account. Even with the email address it's not giving me the actual account. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I merged them. For future reference (mainly people searching for "retrieve account"), the procedure is the same as outlined here:

[How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801).

Answer (score 0):

One time when I was having trouble I emailed the support team. They replied very quickly and fixed my issue, which turned out to be user error in my case :/

Comment: I emailed them 1 hour ago. Still did not listen anything. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your account?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/400859/zeb

I have flagged this question for a mod or dev to see and merge your accounts.  If you are still using the same email address that your account was originally created with, you should still be logged in to your original account when you log in.

Comment: Yes this one is mine:(